# I have an input field that accepts whole numbers for ex: 2, while leaving that field it should automatically format to 2.00

Tags: angular, ecmascript-6

I'm using a directive which accepts only numbers.
I have an input field that accepts whole numbers for ex: 2, while leaving that field it should automatically format to 2.00.

```
const isValid = value => _.isEmpty(value) || (new RegExp(/^(\d{0,6})(\.
(\d{1,2}))?$/)).test(value);

function link(scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
/* @desc Will process each time the value is updated by the user. */
ctrl.$parsers.unshift((value) => {
const valid = isValid(value);
ctrl.$setValidity('decimalNumber', valid);
return valid ? value : undefined;
});

/* @desc Will process each time the value is updated on the DOM element. */
ctrl.$formatters.unshift((value) => {
ctrl.$setValidity('decimalNumber', isValid(value));
return value;
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the (blur) event in the input field and bind it to a method in order to format the value. `<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="value" (blur)="changeFormat()">`